# How to decrypt sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr MD5, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

Have a good day everybody, I'm working with SQL SERVER 2008, developing a simple login. Now I'm encrypting the password with this funtion

> SUBSTRING(sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5', @cont)),3,32)

It's work perfect, if I put pass = 123 then return 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70, but I need to know how to decrypt and return again 123

I hope somebody can help me, Thanks

Comment: MD5 It's a hash. It's not encryption. Hash. [a **one way** hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: then how to return this hash to the original value

Comment: You cannot.  That's the point of a one way hash like MD5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 is a hash, its like an Identifier of a value, so it might or might not contain the actual data.